# App crash after modification on the XIB files

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, crash, uisearchbar, xib

After adding a new searchbar on the RootViewController.xib, and connecting it with the FileOwner, the App will crash. It reports the stack when crash:

```
2011-07-17 17:12:43.756 TableView[1397:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController 
_loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "RootViewController" nib but the view outlet 
 was not set.'
 *** Call stack at first throw:
 (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc85a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f1c313 objc_exception_throw + 44

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00d80ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136

3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d80e6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58

4   UIKit                               0x0036a709 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 295

5   UIKit                               0x00368134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120

6   UIKit                               0x004c1dd8 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 80

7   UIKit                               0x0036800e -[UIViewController view] + 56

8   UIKit                               0x003667f5 -[UIViewController nextResponder] + 34

9   UIKit                               0x003874a6 -[UIResponder _containsResponder:] + 41

10  UIKit                               0x00371c4e -[UINavigationController defaultFirstResponder] + 80

11  UIKit                               0x00386647 -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 42

12  UIKit                               0x00386663 -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 70

13  UIKit                               0x00386406 -[UIResponder(Internal) _promoteDeepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 42

14  TableView                           0x00002a0a -[TableViewAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 135

15  UIKit                               0x002b8c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163

16  UIKit                               0x002bad88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439

17  UIKit                               0x002c5617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533

18  UIKit                               0x002bdabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71

19  UIKit                               0x002c2f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576

20  GraphicsServices                    0x01720992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550

21  CoreFoundation                      0x00da9944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52

22  CoreFoundation                      0x00d09cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215

23  CoreFoundation                      0x00d06f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979

24  CoreFoundation                      0x00d06840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208

25  CoreFoundation                      0x00d06761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97

26  UIKit                               0x002ba7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623

27  UIKit                               0x002c6c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
28  TableView                           0x00002960 main + 102
29  TableView                           0x000028f1 start + 53
30  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
 )

 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't know what you want us to tell you more then your error is already telling you.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "RootViewController" nib **but
>   the view outlet was not set.**'

That is that you forgot to connect your view outlet of your RootViewController so it does not know what to load. The RootViewController of your MainWindow is the first thing that's going to be loaded, if it does not know what view it should display it will give you the above error.

Comment: I am new to the iphone development and feel it is strange because: The application works well, so the controller view shall connect to the mainwindow. It crash only after the searchbar is added. BTW, I connected the searchbar with RootViewController.

Comment: What did you connected the searchbar with in the RootViewController?

Comment: in the Interface Builder:SearchBar connections: control click the searchbar, and then connect to File's Owner. In addition, Right click on the searchbar, and connect the delegate to the File's Owner.

Comment: Not how you did it, what did you connected the searchabar to in the RootViewController. If you look at the RootViewControllers connections tab you should see a name of a property that it connected the searchbar to.

Comment: In the RootViewController.h, I declared a IBOutlet named searchbar, and it connects to the UISearchBar I created on the tableView. In the connection tab you mentioned, there is only one link for the UISearchBar: delegate -- File's Owner under the Outlets section.

Comment: Thanks Cyprian. I managed to fix the issue. The Rootcause shall be another table in the tableview. Before adding the searchbar, it works, after adding the searchbar, the outlet may be changed. After setting the outlet property of the table, everything becomes normal.